# Old B movie with shapeshifting alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, b-movies

Trying to find this old movie I saw when I was like 12. I believe it was set in a small town, there was a shapeshifting alien that could take the form of anyone. I think a special ops team comes to take it out but they can, the alien didn't only shapeshifter it could like rapidly heal itself to.

In the end they nuke the town to kill it. I think they also made a sequel, it wasn't set in a town it was in some kind of facility, and they found some kind of acid like substance that would dissolve and kill the alien.

Comment: When were you 12? You also tagged this [[tag:sy-fy]], did you watch it on that channel?

Comment: Is it possible these are the Mimic movies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Interceptor Force](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167215/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) (1999).

> In the near future, the government has created an elite team of
>   soldiers specially trained in the event of a hostile alien encounter.
>   A multi-national force of the world's best, they are known as the
>   Interceptor Force. A covert early warning satellite network tracks an
>   object crash landing in a town in the Pacific Northwest. Within
>   minutes of the impact, all communication with the town is mysteriously
>   severed. The news sources are given a false story of contamination and
>   the area is sealed off. AWAC's and fighters patrol the perimeter. As
>   the silence from the town continues, the Interceptor team lead by
>   Lieutenant Sean Lambert (Gruner) is sent in to investigate. An MC 130
>   Talon is scrambled for Lambert and his team to make the high altitude
>   air drop. Once inside, the team encounters an alien race capable of
>   assuming human likeness, hiding their reptilian form. Simultaneously
>   the government has given the team less than 24 hours to terminate this
>   alien force before launching an air strike with tactical nukes to
>   completely sterilize the area. Lambert and his team now must battle
>   this alien military force as the clock ticks and a squadron carrying
>   certain death approaches.

The film spawned an equally terrible sequel, [Interceptor Force 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0316030/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

Comment: yes!!! thank you thank you!